# DOM: Finding all defined prefixes+namespaces in an Element

Tags: java, dom

What i'm working on is: I have an xml-tree and i rebuild it with some small changes in a second xml-tree (I don't make any changes on the old tree). Here's an example of the xml-code i'm currently working on.

```
<foo xmlns="http://some.name/space"
  xmlns:ns2="http://some.other/name/space"
  schemaLocation="http://some.name/space        ../../Schema1.xsd
                  http://some.other/name/space  ../../Schema2.xsd
                  http://third.name/space       ../../Schema3.xsd">

  <bar xsi:type="ns2:ApplePie">
    <ns2:apple xmlns:ns3="http://third.name/space">
      <ns3:choclate name="Lindt" form="round">
        <ns3:blackChoclate xsi:type"ns3:YummyBlackChoclate">
          ...
        </ns3:blackChoclate>
      </ns3:choclate>
    </ns2:apple>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

When i've got the `Element` that represents `<ns3:blackChoclate>` I want to find out which prefixes+namespaces are defined at that point.

I want to know that because i have to move the black Choclate element to some other place in the new xml-tree and for that i need to know which of the used prefixes are defined later than in the `foo` element.

Currently i'm just going "upwards" through the tree with `.getParentNode(...)` and search for `xmlns:...` attributes, but i wanted to know if there's an easier way to find out which prefixes+namespaces are defined at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way of achieving this is to keep track of the namespaces and prefixes in a map while iterating over the dom-document!

You should have a HashMap holding the prefix as key and a list of Strings for the namespaces (list because you can redefine prefixes!)